# Unwanted space bib item

Tags: bibtex

I have the following bib item:

```
@ARTICLE{Tollmien,
author          = "W. Tollmien", 
title           = "{\"U}ber di{\"e} {E}ntstehung der {T}urbulenz", 
journal         = "{Nachr. Ges. Wiss. G{\"o}ttingen Math.-Phys. Kl.}", 
pages           = "21--44", 
volume          = "", 
year            = "1929", 
}
```

The volume of the article is not stated (I don't believe there is one). This creates unwanted blank space in the reference. Removing the 'volume' line doesn't alter the problem.

Any ideas about how I should go about resolving this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use biblatex or BibTeX? If it's the latter, which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Incidentally, should there really be an Umlaut on the "e" in "die"?

Comment: BibTeX.
Correct, I got carried away with the Umlaut's - good spot. Thanks.

Comment: I've downloaded and looked at the first few pages of the entire bound volume, and I'd argue that the `@article` entry type isn't a good choice for the entry at hand. I'd use either `@inbook` or `@misc`.

Comment: I'm just trying to be consistent with the references provided in other journals.

Comment: With `biblatex` (which I gather you do not actually use?) I don't get any problems, but `biblatex` is very clever. I suspect that some `.bst` expect an `@article` to have a `volume` field (and that assumption is not that unreasonable, I think) and do not have a punctuation exit strategy, if that is not the case, leaving you with a mess of superfluous punctuation. I would also tend to say this is an `@article` in which you can give the volume as `1929`, or you use `@incollection`

Comment: Which bibliography style *do* you use?

Comment: I don't get the problem you mention under `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. Could you provide more context so we can replicate the problem?

Comment: Do you have any news for us, for example an MWE?